# Reference Request on Order Theory topics

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, order-theory, sorting

I am looking for some references (especially a good recent book) that covers important topics involving partial orders such as: order polytopes, sorting/selection in partially ordered sets, upper and lower bounds on the amount of linear extensions in a width $w$ partially ordered set, and perhaps even algorithms for computing some of these things. Might anyone perhaps know a good book that covers some or all of these topics? For example, the Art of Computer Programming by Knuth covers a lot of the topics on sorting and selection, but only involving total orders - I would be looking for something similar involving partially ordered sets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best references I know on order theory is the third chapter of Richard Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics, Volume I*. A manuscript of this is available by the author [here.](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/)  The topics aren't computer science oriented though, and cover lattices, Möbius functions, and some other interesting topics. It requires a fair bit of mathematical maturity, but the exercises section at the end of the chapter basically summarizes a lot of interesting old and present research in the field.

For sorting on posets I think you're looking for the concept of [topsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort), which I'm pretty sure Knuth covers somewhere in TAOCP as the wikipedia article cites Volume 1, section 2.2.3 as a place for further recommended reading.

Comment: Thanks Sam! - I've taken a look at the Enumerative Combinaotirics reference you provided, and this looks like the type of things I was looking for. I feel that these tools will prove useful in my research later on. As for the topic of Topological Sort, I was looking for things closer to the information theoretic minimum in-term of comparisons/queries made. I am reading a paper called "Sorting and Selection in Posets", and was looking for something of that flavor.

Comment: Roman's "Lattices and Ordered Sets" (2008) is good. If you browse the computer science shelves, you'll find a lot of topics on orders complementary to what's covered there, eg complexity of orders.